# Strange behavior from a dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

In a class define a dictionary, which need restart according to some application events. If the application window has focus, so good ... but if not so I get:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

This is the relevant code:

```
private var seleccion:Dictionary= new Dictionary();

private function myfunction():void{
    trace(stage);//it is always [object Stage]
    if(seleccion){ //always there
        trace(seleccion);////it is always [object Dictionary]
        seleccion= new Dictionary();//if have focus, ok. If not i get error #1009
    }
}
```

I simplified the code to leave only that relevant to the question (I think) ... Any idea why this happens and how I can prevent it?

Comment: Which line number is the error occurring on? A null pointer exception doesn't really doesn't make sense here. The objects in the code you've shown that could possibly be null are `stage` and `seleccion`. But you say these always have values, so what gives? Please show more code or at least tell us which line the error is occurring on.

Comment: After thinking about this a little more, the only thing that really could be null (in the code that you've shown) is the `stage`. The reason is that if `seleccion` was null, the code in the `if` statement wouldn't be executed. I've worked w/Flash for years, and would be surprised if the `stage` is null when the browser doesn't have focus. But who knows :)

Comment: The error appears on the next line: seleccion= new Dictionary();//if have focus, ok. If not i get error #1009

Comment: Something is not right. If your code has an if statement like this: `if (seleccion)` then when `seleccion` is null, the statement statement that throws the null pointer exception should never get executed. Perhaps you may want to show more of your code, is the code for `myFunction` above the complete code you're using? Also, I made a simple test that creates a new Dictionary via a Timer. I click a button to start the timer, and then focus another app. When the timer finishes, it makes a new Dictionary w/out error. It doesn't sound like the Dictionary is the problem...

Comment: @SunilD.: The _if_ is there precisely for that ... ie put it after detecting the problem, because the variable _selection_ is created with the class. There are thousands of related lines, in 14 or 15 classes that interact, but it would be impossible to put it all here ... Right now I think it could be a collision with another variable homonymous, but can't find ... Thanks for trying.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, at least it makes more sense now. But unfortunately, I don't think anyone can help unless you include more code.

Answer (score 1):

As said, it seems to be more a stage problem.
Try to initialize you code via the event ADDED_TO_STAGE like the below:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite {

        public function Main() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            //your code should start here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The stage is fine, the problem is with _seleccion_